# Give object same field value as a field of its Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-models

Summary: I have two related models and want them to share a field (`zip_code`):

```
class Business(models.Model):
    #other fields
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
 class Job(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete = "models.CASCADE") 
    zip_code = business.zip_code #Does not work
```

Full Description:

I am trying to create a job board website. The user enters a zip code and jobs in a specified radius should be returned. Here is my models.py:

```
class Business(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length = 10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name +", " + self.address + ", " + self.state

class Job(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete = "models.CASCADE")
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    zip_code = business.zip_code

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + " - " + self.business.name
```

Upon attempting to filter `Job` objects by zip code:

```
jobs_in_zip = Job.objects.all().filter(zip_code = zip_code)
```

I realized the `Job` model did not have a `zip_code` field. I tried updating the model as such:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete = "models.CASCADE")
    zip_code = business.zip_code
```

but this returned `AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'zip_code'`

How should I go about this? Thanks in advance.

PS: If you have a better title in my mind feel free to change it, I don't think I clearly defined the problem that well.

Comment: You will have to overrite the `save` method of `Job` model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find an example below. Essentially, you need to overwrite the `save` method of your `Job` class:

```
class Algorithm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)

class JobLog(models.Model):
    task_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)
    algorithm = models.ForeignKey(Algorithm, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.task_name = self.algorithm.name + "-" + self.task_id
        super(JobLog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

For your purpose:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete = "models.CASCADE")
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    zip_code = business.zip_code

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + " - " + self.business.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.zip_code = self.business.zip_code
        super(Job, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```